# How to create a comment system in Laravel similar to WordPress (with and without user Auth)

Tags: laravel, wordpress, authentication, comments, blogs

I want to create a comment system for my Laravel blog site.
I want all users to be able to post their comments even without logging in and registering (exactly similar to the WordPress comment system).

But I don't know the best way to do this because I know there are many fake users in the system and many fake emails are added to the users table for the blog.
How can I implement this correctly?
Thank you in advance for your help.

One method that came to my mind is to completely separate anonymous users from the users table and keep the users who do not register in it. But I don't know if this is correct in terms of software engineering.